# How to troubleshoot ASP.NET app never loading in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET app (.NET Framework) deployed to an ec2 instance running Windows Server and IIS. The app never loads in my browser - it just spins forever. This is true for .aspx pages as well as simple static .html pages.

**What I've tried so far**

- Loading the website as localhost from a browser on the server itself...no luck
- Website physical path is correct
- Website binding matches what I've used on other servers

  - `<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:*" sslFlags="0" />`
- Windows permissions look OK (both the app pool user and IIS_IUSRS have full control)
- The app pool looks OK (Mode=Integrated; Identity=ApplicationPoolIdentity)
- Server Roles and Features look OK (Web Server role, .NET Framework 3.5/4.6 Features, etc.)
- This ASP.NET app works fine on other machines
- I created a simple "HelloWorld" website in IIS on this same server - it loads fine
- I tried adding logging to `Global.asax.cs`, but it seemingly never gets hit
- I don't see any traffic in IIS logs
- I don't see any obvious issues in the Windows Event Viewer (I do see lots of activity, but nothing that points to a problem with my app, as far as I can tell)
- Disabled proxy settings in Chrome
- Viewed network traffic in Chrome - the request just shows as "Pending" and never returns

This is frustrating, because I can't seem to get any logs or information about what might be the problem. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef You need to start testing the site from the server itself first, and then move on to other network setup. Don't be frustrated when you didn't yet start serious troubleshooting. What I guess is that you didn't get the networking settings right, so the packets never land on the server from remote. Tools like Wireshark can easily tell you more.

Comment: All of this testing was done on the server itself...so trying to load localhost from a browser on the server. Sorry I did not make that clear. Can you recommend any specific "serious troubleshooting" steps?

Comment: 1. Describe the site binding you set, as that controls what URL you can use locally or remotely, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html 2. What web browser are you using right now? Disable its proxy settings, and open its developer tools to learn the network packets.

Comment: Added the relevant binding to the original post. It matches what I have used for other servers/sites. I am using Chrome incognito. I disabled the proxy settings. I don't see anything helpful in the developer console: the request just spins forever in "Pending" status. Occasionally it fails immediately with a 503 error. But then if I refresh it's back to spinning forever.

Comment: Gradually you started to go deeper and revealed more about this web app on the server. That's good, and you might try the next few tips: 1. Switch to an HTTP binding and see if things start to work 2. If you intend to use HTTPS, run a report to see what common issues are out there, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Is your problem solved? Do you get any other error messages when he spins forever? For example you can check your console.

Comment: No, my problem is not solved. I have not found any error messages. I don't see any information on the Chrome developer console, if that's the console you are referring to.

Comment: I got the website to load, but only after (1) deleting the app and app pool, (2) deleting the app from disk, and (3) re-creating the app and app pool. Everything seems to be the same, but it works now. No idea what the problem is or how to troubleshoot next time it happens (this is the second time this has happened to me).